# Telegram curl text "%device" error "Bad Request: text must be encoded in UTF-8"

Tags: curl, utf-8, telegram, prtg

We're using Telegram notifications to get status of our Virtual Machines and other services using PRTG Monitoring Tool.

#### Problem

Notificacions are not working via CURL and POST

#### Configuration

```
curl -X POST https://api.telegram.org/<BOT_ID>/sendMessage -d 'chat_id=<CHAT_ID>&parse_mode=Markdown&text=%lastmessage %linksensor %since %group %device'
```

#### Error

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: text must be encoded in UTF-8"}
```

#### Testing

Playing with the configuration we noticed that Removing "%device" will make it work.

#### Question

It is a problem with the value "%device" in the Telegram Api via CURL or POST?

**It is necessary for us to use "%device" value as it points to a PRTG Internal Variable.**

Comment: Maybe `%25device` instead of `%device`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a telegram related problem. I guess that for some reason you have non UTF-8 symbols in your %device name (after the substitution)

Comment: Without using PRTG internal variables, only with the curl in my terminal, the word "%device" still break and show the UTF-8 Error.
`curl -X POST https://api.telegram.org/<BOT_ID>/sendMessage -d 'chat_id=<CHAT_ID>&parse_mode=Markdown&text=%device'`

So it seems to be related with some type of "banned" word for Telegram API ?

Comment: @JosefZ I've tried this, and seems to work fine, the word "%device" shows in my Telegram chat. But in the console of PRTG, of course, the variable is not showing because is not named "%25device". Still seems to be a Telegram issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also encountered this. If you use the synonym placeholder **%server** instead of **%device**, then everything starts working.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be a solution for this specific problem with PRTG but is still not working in Telegram Sentence. I'll continue with the investigation.